# RSS Feed Generator caching Using varnish

Tags: caching, rss, varnish

I want to write an RSS feed generator application.

I want to know if varnish or similar caching solution can be used for caching the RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, caching an RSS feed application with Varnish will work very well.

Just send the usual "Cache-Control: max-age=XXX" response header from your application, and Varnish will happily cache it for the duration.

I've seen that some RSS clients send a "?forceupdate=" GET argument to RSS feeds. Depending on your traffic levels and requirements you might want to do some request URL sanitation to handle that:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "/rss/") {
        # remove any GET arguments to increase cache hit rate
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
    }
}
```